# how to use meal_item method using link_to in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know how to use `meal_item` method using a `link_to`:

```
def meal_item
  @menus = Menu.where(:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id],:item_type=>'Half').sorted    
  @cart = current_cart  
end
```

i am using this link_to:

```
<%= link_to("MEAL",{:controller=>'menus',:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id], :method => :post}
```

I want to stay in index page and use `meal_item` method only.

Comment: I guess you just need to add `action` to the `link_to`.`<%= link_to("MEAL",{:controller=>'menus',:action => 'meal_item',:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id], :method => :post} %>`

Comment: after used '<%= link_to("MEAL",{:controller=>'menus',:action => 'meal_item',:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id], :method => :post}, class:'linkstyle ')%>' this code the page gets redirected to Menus#show.Why this is happen.

Comment: I am getting below code in my terminal: 'Started GET "/menus/meal_item?hotel_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-22 21:15:25 +0530
Processing by MenusController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"hotel_id"=>"1", "id"=>"meal_item"}
  ←[1m←[35mHotel Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT  `hotels`.* FROM `hotels`  WHERE `hotels`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered menus/show.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)'